# Why is the blog text removed over Bull's head in Sherlock : A scandal in Belgravia?

Tags: analysis, sherlock

In the episode *A scandal in Belgravia* (Sherlock season 2 episode 1), when Dr. Watson is blogging and his blog text is shown to the viewers overlaid on the wall of 221B, Baker St., why is the text that comes atop the Bull's Head ***erased***?

Comment: I rather assumed that the text was supposed to be/imagined to be on the wall so that the bull's head covered it up.

Comment: The same show-runner, Steven Moffat, also uses on-screen text (to a lesser effect) on his other show, *Doctor Who*. A good example is the beginning of the episode "[The Bells of St. John](http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/the-bells-of-saint-john-pics-batch-1.jpg)." Also [this](http://i60.tinypic.com/wrxe74.jpg) from the same episode.

Answer (score 6):

I really don't think there's any significance to that.
It's just a video effects choice. When done this way, the blog text seems to be a part of the wall.

Comment: Yes, he is posting _on his wall_.(facebook reference) :))

Answer (score 5):

The onscreen text interacting with the environment is a stylistic choice and happens more often than you may think. The **reason** for the text itself is to convey important information in an interesting way, avoiding the tedious and clunky ways [exposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposition_(narrative)) is often presented. It also seems to fit with the unorthodox way Sherlock's mind works (seeing things others do not, etc).

Sometimes the text disappears when walked across or in the case of Mary's "Liar" swirls around the two. It can also conform to the shape (like a face) it is mentally projected onto. Once, it was a timer. In the same episode you ask about, the text onscreen is even refected in a window.

[image: On face]
[image: being walked across]
[image: "Liar" swirling around them]
[image: timer]
[image: hny]

It adds depth and weight to the thoughts behind the words, much the way the titles of the film [Panic Room](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqIclb4qsJI) seemed to ominously float around the city.

Comment: The best ever word-scene overlap I ever seen is [Zombieland open credit](http://youtu.be/NVYP46ecl4Y?t=3m22s). **WARNING** : gore content.